# IIS applicaiton HTTP method stop running

Tags: iis

I have Web application on IIS server.

I have `POST` method that take a long time to run (Around 30-40min).

After period time the application stop running (Without any exception).

I set `Idle timeout` to be `0` and It is not help for me.

What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all the work initiated by the request before responding at all:

1. Receive the request
2. Put the information in the request in a queue (which you could manage with a database table, ZeroMQ, or whatever else you like)
3. Respond with a "Request recieved" message.

That way you respond within seconds, which is acceptable for HTTP.

Then have a separate process monitor the queue and process the data on it (doing the 30-40 minute long job). When the job is complete, notify the user.

You could do this through the browser with [a Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) or through [a WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or use a completely different mechanism (such as by sending an email to the user who made the request).